# .htaccess custom error document using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble working with error documents on a hosting (GoDaddy).

Here is my htaccess content:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-4 .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NE]

ErrorDocument 404 /error/NotFound
ErrorDocument 403 /error/Forbidden

RedirectMatch ^/\+(.*)$ http://plus.google.com/[my_profile]


#Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage es-PE

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*yahoo.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot
[...]
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent “(Ubuntu-feisty)$” bad_bot

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
#Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
   [...]
</ifModule>
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
#COUNTRY_BLOCK_START 
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
allow from [ip_range]
deny from all
</Limit>
```

With all of this, custom error pages not working.

Comment: Have you tried placing your ErrorDocument declarations up at the beginning of the file?

Comment: It works :D, I can't understand... I only had to remove the / previous to error and put it at the beginning file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .html, .php or whatever the extension is for the error files to

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/NotFound(.html)
ErrorDocument 403 /error/Forbidden(.html)
```

Or if the file extensions have been removes using the .htaccess file, the add a slash to

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/NotFound/
ErrorDocument 403 /error/Forbidden/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is handling all requests that are for files that don't exist (which would trigger a 404). What you need to do is in your routing script (`index.php`), look for when a route doesn't exist, then return your error document from there.

Because of these conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Anything that would normally fall under a 404 error would be caught and routed to your `index.php` script.

Comment: If the page I'm looking for doesn't exists I handle it using: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

Comment: @JuanCarlosVegaNeira Because of that, your `ErrorDocument 404` *will never be evaluated*, that means in your index.php, you need to return your custom error document.